# error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown in stream()

Tags: java, file, lambda

I'm trying to write a File and here is the code:

```
    public static void writeFile(File f, int n) throws IOException{
    //reads n teams which go to next phase

    try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f))){
        table.stream()
         .sorted()
         .limit(n)
         .forEachOrdered(x->writer.write(x.getName()));
        /*for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            writer.write(table.get(i).getName());
            writer.newLine();
        }*/ this if uncommented works great!
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and I get this error when I try to compile:

Counter.java:123: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
             .forEachOrdered(x->writer.write(x.getName()));

My doubt:  Even if I declare the IOException in the method I am using the .forEachOrdered() I can't use it because the method which I define inside the .forEachOrdered() (which is a Consumer) doesn't declare it? I don't know if I am clear, but maybe you could infer something just looking at the code. Thanks.

Note: the table is a declared static list with Teams.

Comment: What's wrong with doing an ordinary `for` loop? It's simple, clear, and already works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the signature for `forEachOrdered` requires a `Consumer` and a `Consumer` does not declare that its `accept` method can throw any checked exceptions.

[JLS 11.2.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3) says:

> It is a compile-time error if a lambda body can throw some exception class E when E is a checked exception class and E is not a subclass of some class declared in the throws clause of the function type targeted by the lambda expression.

Therefore, the `IOException` must be caught by the lambda itself.  The recommended solutions<sup>1</sup> are:

- catch and handle it within the lambda, or
- catch it in the lambda and rethrow it wrapped in an unchecked exception, then catch / handle the wrapped exception at the outer level.  @Hank D's answer illustrates this.

The problem with handling the IOException within the lambda is that the "for each" will continue running.

---

<sup>1 - There is also the "sneaky throw" approach where you call a special method that subverts the Java rules and throws a checked exception without letting on.  But it is "nasty", and I'm not sure it would directly help here.  You would need to catch the `IOException` and sneakily rethrow it in the lambda.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You could catch the `IOException` and rethrow it wrapped in an UncheckedIOException, like this:

```
.forEachOrdered(x-> {
     try{
         writer.write(x.getName()));
     } catch (IOException e) {
         throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
     }
}
```

The stream will not continue processing if an IOException is thrown.

Outside of the stream, you should then change your catch to

```
    } catch (IOException | UncheckedIOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You might create convenience functional types that take care of the try/catch for you, something like

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface CheckedIOConsumer<T> {

    void accept(T t) throws IOException;

    static <T> Consumer<T> toUnchecked(CheckedIOConsumer<T> consumer) {
        return t -> {
            try {
                consumer.accept(t);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

which would make your terminal function

```
.forEachOrdered(toUnchecked(x -> writer.write(x.getName())));
```